# Vue кнопка уведомлений

Tags: vue.js

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть кнопка push

```
    <el-switch class="ui_toggle__zone" v-model="value"></el-switch>
```

при нажатии на нее все работает. Но если нажать на ссылку "Push-уведомления", то ничего не происходит. Как сделать, чтобы кнопка работала если на нее просто нажали и работала по клику на ссылку "Push-уведомления"?

Код проекта - https://jsfiddle.net/5st4r9a8/

Answer (score 0):

Меняйте value самостоятельно по клику на ваш div

```
<div class="ui_toggle__label l-fs-14 l-ml-10" @click="value = !value">Push-уведомления</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/68ry2bnq/